# Recursively download zip files from webpage (Windows)

Tags: regex, r, download

Is it possible to download all zip files from a webpage without specifying the individual links one at a time.

I would like to download all monthly account zip files from http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html.

I am using Windows 8.1, R3.1.1. I do not have `wget` on the PC so can't use a recursive call.

**Alternative:** 
As a workaround i have tried downloading the webpage text itself. I would then like to extract the name of each zip file which i can then pass to `download.file` in a loop. However, i am struggling with extracting the name.

```
pth <- "http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html"

temp <- tempfile()
download.file(pth,temp)
dat <- readLines(temp)
unlink(temp)

g <- dat[grepl("accounts_monthly", tolower(dat))]
```

`g` contains character strings with the file names, amongst other characters.

```
g
 [1] "                    <li><a href=\"Accounts_Monthly_Data-September2013.zip\">Accounts_Monthly_Data-September2013.zip  (775Mb)</a></li>"
 [2] "                    <li><a href=\"Accounts_Monthly_Data-October2013.zip\">Accounts_Monthly_Data-October2013.zip  (622Mb)</a></li>"
```

I would like to extract the name of the files `Accounts_Monthly_Data-September2013.zip` and so on, but my regex is quite terrible (see for yourself)

```
    gsub(".*\\>(\\w+\\.zip)\\s+", "\\1", g)
```

data

```
g <- c("                    <li><a href=\"Accounts_Monthly_Data-September2013.zip\">Accounts_Monthly_Data-September2013.zip  (775Mb)</a></li>", 
"                    <li><a href=\"Accounts_Monthly_Data-October2013.zip\">Accounts_Monthly_Data-October2013.zip  (622Mb)</a></li>"
)
```

Comment: Nice question.  This is not easy to figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `XML` package:

```
pth <- "http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html"
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(pth)
myfiles <- doc["//a[contains(text(),'Accounts_Monthly_Data')]", fun = xmlAttrs]
fileURLS <- file.path("http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk", myfiles)
mapply(download.file, url = fileURLS, destfile = myfiles)
```

`"//a[contains(text(),'Accounts_Monthly_Data')]"` is an [XPATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression. It instructs the XML package to select all nodes that are anchors( `a` ) containing text "Accounts_Monthly_Data". This results is a list of nodes. The `fun = xmlAttrs` argument then tells the XML package to pass these nodes to the `xmlAttrs` function. This function strips the attributes from xml nodes. The anchor only have one attribute in this case the `href` which is what we are looking for.