# Try Catch not catching "error : unknown IO error" - I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: r, try-catch, ioerror, xbrl

The code underneath is part of a function.
The getLatestFileName function gets a correct fileName (locally stored).

The error is caused by the tryCatch expression: result <- try(xbrlDoAll...)
Even though I tried to catch it with a try function and a try catch, I even  changed options to show.error.messages = FALSE.
I keep getting following output which causes R to crash:

[1] "FINAL STEP"

[1] "STEP 1"

error : Unknown IO error

I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://xbrl.us/us-gaap/1.0/elts/us-gaap-all-2008-03-31.xsd"

Based on what I got printed, I suppose the error is caused by the XBRL package, when it tries to get info from the url above.

Can someone help me out?

```
  instance <- getLatestFileName(ticker, date, type)
  options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  result <- NA
  #result <- try(xbrlDoAll(instance, cache.dir = "XBRLcache", prefix.out = NULL), silent = TRUE)

  tryCatch({
      print("STEP 1")
      options(show.error.messages = FALSE)
      result <- try(xbrlDoAll(instance, cache.dir = NULL, prefix.out =  NULL), silent = TRUE)
      print("STEP2")
    }, warning <- function(w) {
      result <- NA
      print("WARNING")
    }, error = function(e) {
      result <- NA
      print(result)
      print("Test")
    }, finally <- {
      print("FINAL STEP")
    })

  try(is.na(result))
  print("we did get here")
```

Comment: What happens, if you only run `xbrlDoAll(instance, verbose = T)`?

Comment: @Christoph
The package is trying to get the schema, and is looking at the cache folder for a file, this file is empty, as the url from where this file is generated does no longer exist.

The error is visible at the last lines:

`D:/Thesis_Bram_Lavens/DataLost/raw_data/ABB/20-F/2009-03-10/2008-12-31/abb-20081231.xsd  ==> Schema:  http://xbrl.us/us-gaap/1.0/elts/us-gaap-all-2008-03-31.xsd 
Schema:  http://xbrl.us/us-gaap/1.0/elts/us-gaap-all-2008-03-31.xsd 
Using file from cache dir...
XBRLcache/us-gaap-all-2008-03-31.xsd:1: parser error : Document is empty
Elements`

Comment: Sorry for the editing! I tried to get the formatting correct, first time I really post on stackoverflow

Comment: Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930936/parse-multiple-xbrl-files-stored-in-a-zip-file) help?

Comment: @Christoph, what exactly do you mean by 'that'? 

My focus is on catching the error.
The reason the error occurs is because this url: http://xbrl.us/us-gaap/1.0/elts/us-gaap-all-2008-03-31.xsd
is no longer working. 
At this moment, I don't want to fix this, I just want my code to handle it and continue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this specific issue by placing all taxonomy files from 2008 in my XBRLCache folder.

I downloaded the correct files (not empty as what the error was) at this link:

http://xbrl.us/documents/XBRLUSGAAPTaxonomies-2008-03-31.zip

There can be a problem with loading the page as I saw it did not always work.
Probably those servers are too busy..

I hope this works for other people as well!

Too bad I did not solve the not catching problem..